# Strange email about Ask Different from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

So recently I got an email from Stack Overflow saying that I am in the top whatever percent of rep earning users.

What I found strange though is that it's from Stack Overflow, not Stack Exchange or Ask Different.

The email looks legit but I am not sure if it is and why it came from Stack Overflow.

The email:

[image: email]

Comment: Congratulations and keep up the good work. I clearly remember and can attest receiving similar email a few months ago when I started with Ask Different!. Hope to see you in the monthly most active contributors list. Good luck :)

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks

Comment: @WayToDoor How can I censor it better?

Comment: With a fully black rectangle like this https://snaps.api-d.com/HPQoc.jpg

Comment: @WayToDoor Thanks for your help, could you please delete the comment that shows part of the email? Thanks

Comment: @DManokhin done, stay safe :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two things here:

- If you look at the transport logs (and not the "from") you can see in fact the email is from Stack Overflow
- The email itself matches what others receive

On both fronts I can confirm this email looks like an legitimate email from the Stack Exchange network. That being said, it's always possible for a spammer to take that mail content and send it to you with different links - so you can always decline to click any links until you verify them in any email.

Many emails generated by the network (e.g. newsletters, etc) will be sent from Stack Overflow, so this is not a concern even though it's referencing your Ask Different registration.

As for the email itself, I've checked and can confirm this is a legitimate email that goes out to new users if they achieve a certain amount of reputation within a particular period.

In short, **this looks very much like nothing to be concerned about** and, in fact, you can pat yourself on the back for being an active member of the community as well as knowing that phishing mails can be sent that look great.

Most importantly, Thank you for your contributions here!